# ServiceStack Admin UI respinse not visible

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

Sometimes in ServiceStack Admin UI I cant’t view the response for some request. I can’t understand why and there isn’t errors in developer tool console. I’m using ServiceStack v8 (also tried to update but nothing seems change)

```
public class Test : IReturn<IEnumerable<TestResult>>
{
//Some properties…
}
public class TestResult { /* some proeprties…*/}
```